# Is it possible to find integer $n$, $m$ so $6n=7m+1$ without manual search?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I was dealing with a childish problem, which eventually led to this:

> Find integer $n$ and $m$ to fit the equation $6n=7m+1$

I immediately found first numbers by simple enumeration ($n=6$, $m=5$). But later I spent half of the day to figure out whether it's possible to have some general solution to the problem or at least any solution without manual enumeration.. I found nothing. So is it possible? Thanks!

Comment: anything is possible

Comment: If $(n_0,m_0)$ is a solution, then $(n_0+7,m_0+6)$ is also a solution.

Comment: $6n - 7m = 1$ is linear diophantine equation. All solutions of these are $n=6 + 7t$, $y=5 + 6t$, $t\in\mathbb Z$

Comment: $$6(n-m)=m+1$$
$$\frac{m+1}{(n-m)}=6$$
chek:
$$if \ \ m,n \ \ odd$$

$$if \ \ m,n \ \ even$$
$$...$$

Comment: $n=m=-1$ is the obvious solution from $7-6=1$ and getting the signs right.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The [extended Euclidean algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm) does this for the general case.

---

With 6 and 7 in particular it is probably easier to note that
$$ 7\cdot 1 + 6 \cdot (-1) = 1 $$
and rearrange this to
$$ 6\cdot(-1) = 7\cdot(-1)+1 $$
If you want positive $n$ and $m$ (though you're just asking for integers, and $-1$ is a perfectly good integer), add $6\cdot 7$ to both sides of this, so you get
$$ 6\cdot(7-1) = 7\cdot(6-1)+1 $$

Answer (score 1):

If $\gcd(a,b)=1$ and 
$$ a x_0 - b y_0 = 1, $$
then *any* integer solution of:
$$ a x - b y = 1 $$
is given by $x=x_0+kb,y=y_0+ka$. So if $(a,b)=(7,6)$, any integer solution of:
$$ 7 x - 6 y = 1 $$
is given by $x=6k+1,y=7k+1$.

Answer (score 1):

Since 6 and 7 are co-prime, your problem is solvable, to begin with. Now, just do a euclidean division between 6 and 7. Euclidean division is an algorithm for producing such Bézout relations.